# Problem Inserting feature with Geotools WFS

Tags: wfs, geotools, wfs-t

With this tutorial

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Data+Writing

When I try to insert a feature

```
try {
DataStore geoToolsClient = getGeoToolsClient();

Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction();
try {

FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> featureWriter = geoToolsClient.getFeatureWriterAppend(typeName, transaction);

            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = featureWriter.next(); // The problem is here!
              simpleFeature.setAttributes(featureToInsert.getAttributes());

              featureWriter.write();

              transaction.commit();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                transaction.rollback();
            throw ex;   
            }
```

This bug occurs at featureWriter.next(); statement which is supposed to provide an empty SimpleFeature. Then, we have to fill and save it.

This attempt to create an empty SimpleFeature by giving a value to NULL nillable attributes and default non nillable attributes.

We have a column of SDO_GEOMETRY type is not nillable in the bind table.

When the "next ()" attempts to create a default value for this attribute, the following method is called to create a default instance:

org.geotools.data.DataUtilities # defaultValue (Class Type)

But then the attribute is "com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry" type and defaultValue method does not know how to create a default instance of this type. This exception is thrown :

throw new IllegalArgumentException(type + " is not supported by this method");

And I’m not able to insert a spatial feature in the database

Thanks for any ideas!

Jeremie

Answer (score 1):

That is a very old (7+ years) tutorial - have a look at http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html which shows how the new FeatureStores work. You'll need something like:

```
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                String name = tokens[2].trim();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].trim());

                /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
                Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

                featureBuilder.add(point);
                featureBuilder.add(name);
                featureBuilder.add(number);
                SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
                features.add(feature);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's useful, but I couldn't promote the answer, I don't have 15 reputations...